# Meaning of “if it struggles” in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does here mean “if it struggles? Is it said about morning that struggles with “the motion lazy swoon”?

UPD: This fragment is indeed from Mallarmé’s ‘L’Après-Midi d’un Faune’. At least as it is presented in “Sinister Resonance” by David Toop

> Through the motionless, lazy swoon suffocating with heat the cool
> morning **if it struggles**, there murmurs no water not poured by my flute
> on the thicket sprinkled with melody; and the only wind, quick to
> breathe itself forth out of the two pipes, before it scatters the
> sound in an arid rain, is, on the horizon unmoved by any wrinkle, the
> visible, calm and artificial breath of inspiration returning to the
> sky.

Comment: Please cite and link the original source text and provide more detailed context before you ask questions on literary interpretation. Otherwise, I have very little idea how to interpret this already abstract text.

Answer (score 1):

Given what extremely limited context I have, I can explain my interpretation of the sentence to you. I will preface this by saying that **this sentence does not follow the typical conventions of English grammar**. It appears to be largely poetic, literary text with a great degree of artistic freedom. As is often the case with literary texts that are intended to portray a *mood or feeling* rather than adhere strictly to grammatical conventions, not all parts of this are going to be completely grammatically correct.

You may have noticed that the entire quote is one sentence. I shall try to break it down:

> “Through the [motionless, lazy swoon] [suffocating with heat the cool morning if it struggles]…”

In this case, “**suffocating**” appears to be a verb. The subject is the “swoon,” the predicate is “suffocating,” and the object is “morning.”